# Blazor server side Virtualize component introduces unexpected div on first place

Tags: blazor-server-side

I am trying to use Virtualize component on a Blazor server-side single page application in order to optimize rendering items on a grid.

But the component always introduces an unexpected div on first place, ruining original columns layout.

Next sample ilustrates this issue with a first grid on a foreach loop, successfully rendering 3 columns and 2 rows, followed by a virtualized grid showing the issue:

```
@page "/test"

<div class="Grid">
    @foreach(var item in items)
    {
        <div>@item</div>   
    }
</div>

<div class="Grid">
    <Virtualize Items="@items" Context="item">
        <div>@item</div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

<style>
    .Grid {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns:min-content min-content min-content;
        grid-column-gap:10px;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private string[] items = new string[] { "A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2" };
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When using **Virtualize** component, the spacer **div** element will inject before and after your content. The spacer elements internally use an Intersection Observer to receive notifications when they're becoming visible.

Styles limitation in virtualize component
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/virtualization?view=aspnetcore-6.0#advanced-styles-and-scroll-detection

```
    @page "/grid-virtualize"

@*<div class="Grid">
    @foreach(var item in items)
    {
        <div>@item</div>
    }
</div>*@


<div class="row">
    <Virtualize Items="@virtualItems" Context="item" ItemSize="25">

        <div class="col">@item</div>

    </Virtualize>
</div>


<style>
    .Grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: min-content min-content min-content;
        grid-column-gap: 10px;
    }

    .row {
        display: flex;
    }

    .col {
        flex-basis: 33.3333%;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private string[] items = new string[] { "A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2" };

    private string[] virtualItems = GetItems();

    private static string[] GetItems()
    {
        string[] items = new string[1000];
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        {
            items[i] = "A" + i;
        }
        {

        }
        return items;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Divya. Your solution works since it does not use CSS Grid. The problem is I need a CSS Grid in the real world because several columns should be differently formatted with widths depending on content length. Is there any way to use CSS Grid with Virtualize component while avoiding the issue of injected spacer div elements?

Comment: According to Steve Sanderson it is intented to not work with grid. See: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/28056 for more info

Answer (score 0):

One way around it is to apply the grid styling to the child element, as long as you're using fixed sized columns. It doesn't make sense to use a column that resizes with the content much anyway, since only the visible content is rendered, so it could cause your layout to jump around quite a bit while scrolling.

```
@page "/test"

<div class="grid">
    <Virtualize Items="@items" Context="item" ItemSize="30">
        <div>
            <p>@item</p>
            <p>hello</p>
            <p>world</p>
        </div>
    </Virtualize>
</div>

<style>
    .grid {
        max-height: 100px;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    .grid div {
        display:grid;
        grid-template-columns: 30px 2fr 8fr;
        height: 30px;
    }
</style>

@code {
    private string[] items = new string[] { "A1", "B1", "C1", "A2", "B2", "C2" };
}
```